# IBM Websphere 7.1 thread dumps

Tags: multithreading

I  am  trying to understand  the  concurreny anaylysis  logged  in thread dumps..
1) Say  i have two threads  A and B, If thread A  hs lock on few  rows (oracle 10g) and my thread B  is trying  to  update  same ROw  soo ideally in my thread dumps  i should get  Thread  B  waiting  for thread A
 Second  Senario 
Now  suppose  Thread A  is  locking on  a block of code and  Thread B tries  to enter and i take thread dumps  soo in my dumos  i should again see  Thread  B trying to  get a monitor  held by thread A..

My question  is from Thread Dumps how can i verify  if  thread A  is  waiting  for a  something that  is  held by  thread A   is  at  Code level  or  query level????

Second Question ....  in  "LOCKS subcomponent dump routine"

I see  many  many locks  but  i couln'd  see   which thread  is  holding  this resource
ie    it should  say like  Own by  thread 10  but  its saying   "unowned"

Third  Question

for reference please refer  below  sample

3XMTHREADINFO      "Multicast Heartbeat Receiver Thread" J9VMThread:0x0000000033896700, j9thread_t:0x00000001217D9FC0, java/lang/Thread:0x000000004E017320, state:CW, prio=5
3XMTHREADINFO1            (native thread ID:0x5CD0E2B, native priority:0x5, native policy:UNKNOWN)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Java callstack:
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/net/PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/net/PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:164(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at java/net/DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:721(Compiled Code))
4XESTACKTRACE                at net/sf/ehcache/distribution/MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver$MulticastReceiverThread.run(MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver.java:124)
3XMTHREADINFO3           Native callstack:
4XENATIVESTACK               _event_wait+0x344 (0x09000000007AD9C8 [libpthreads.a+0x169c8])
4XENATIVESTACK               _cond_wait_local+0x4dc (0x09000000007BBBA0 [libpthreads.a+0x24ba0])
4XENATIVESTACK               _cond_wait+0xc8 (0x09000000007BC18C [libpthreads.a+0x2518c])
4XENATIVESTACK               pthread_cond_wait+0x19c (0x09000000007BCDE0 [libpthreads.a+0x25de0])
4XENATIVESTACK               (0x090000004BD4FB64 [libj9thr24.so+0x4b64])

Now  its in Conditional Wait , But  how can i proceed  the  reason for conditional wait.,. coz  i can't  see any thing like  waiting  on something curretnly    owned is   some thing else??

Answer (score 0):

You have to monitor the lock on resource, and see if the threads  blocked waiting for a condition remain the same during time (possible deadlock) or dynamically change

I strongly advise you to take three java cores with an interval of some minute and then open them with Thread Analyzer

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c

Let us know in case you need more help